# Match cell from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets. Sheet 1 has a lookup value in column A that, if it exists in another sheet, I want to return the value from the cell on the same row in the other sheet but from column D. I have managed to get it working if I hard code the sheet:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A6,Sheet2!B:B,0)),"",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(A6,Sheet2!B:B),0))
```

I don't however want to restrict the search to Sheet2. I have tried to generate a named range SheetList to use with `INDIRECT()` to replace the lookup array like this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A6,(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!B:B")),0)),"",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),MATCH(A6,(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!B:B")),0)))
```

but I can't get it to work. I feel it is time to admit defeat and ask for help!

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only have a few sheets to look through, you can do this quite simply with nested IFERROR statements. IFFERROR first attempts to perform a calculation - if that calculation is valid, it returns the value. If that calculation results in an error, it returns an alternat result as specified by you.

You can use this to check through each sheet, cascading down to the subsequent sheet each time it fails to find a match, as follows [Note that I have adjusted your INDEX to pull the value from column D of any sheet where column B from that sheet matches A6 on the current sheet. This may not be exactly how you want it to pull]:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(A6,Sheet2!B:B)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!D:D,MATCH(A6,Sheet3!B:B)),IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet4!D:D,MATCH(A6,Sheet4!B:B)),""))))
```

This first tries to grab column D from sheet2 where A6 is found on column B from sheet 2; if it errors, it then tries sheet 3, and if that errors it then tries sheet 4. If no match is found in sheet 4, it provides a blank response.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's not quite what I am looking for. Using a column in Sheet1 as my reference (Match value) I would like to search 12 different sheets (sheets 2-13) to find a match in column B, and if it returns a match, to return the value from that sheet where it was identifed but from column D. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

In case you have not solve this yet. Try...

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A6,(INDIRECT("'"&"Sheet2"&"'!"&B:B)),0)),"",INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&"Sheet2"&"'!"A:A),MATCH(A6,(INDIRECT("'"&"Sheet2"&"'!"B:B)),0)))
```

or type the sheetnames in A1 and Range in B1 then reference them

```
...indirect("'"&A1&"'!"&B1)...
```

then you can just change the value in A1 or B1 to make it dynamic :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still not working :-( I don't want to make it dynamic in as such as I want it to automatically search from 13 the different sheets listed in the sheet list. Is adding the & before the range coding it to the current sheet? I want find the value in A6 in sheet one in one of sheets 2-13 and when it does return the value from the winning sheet but from column A. Any other ideas? Thanks again

Comment: `&` is used to concatenate `strings`